# Is there a name for the arguments of the substitution operation?

Tags: logic, terminology

In logic, there is the substitution operation which takes two logical formulae and substitutes one into the other. For example, substituting R→S and T→S for P and Q in the expression P&Q, we obtain:

(R → S) & (T → S).

The substitution of t for x in the formula F is written [t/x]F.
Taking another example, let t be 1, x be x, and F be ∃x.s(x)=0, then [t/x]F yields the formula s(1)=0.

The arguments to the addition operation are called addends or summands. What do we call the arguments to the substitution operation? What do we call t, x, and F above?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added a sentence. Did that help? Addend is to addition as what is to substitution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, $R-S$ is a substituend and $T-S$ is a substituend.  They are substituends.  (You can find this definition in most English language dictionaries.)  There does not appear to be a term for the thing that is to be replaced.  Most constructions I find either explicitly use the replaced symbol or its symbol class to refer to it.  For instance, "... being a substituend of free first-order variables ..." (from N.B. Cocchiarella *[Two Views of the Logic of Plurals and a Reduction of One to the Other](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43649733)*, 2015.)

Answer (score 0):

$F$ is called a *substituting* before $x$ is replaced by $t$;

$t$ is called a *substituend* which is to replace $x$;

$x$ is called a *substituand* or *substituent* which is to be replaced by $t$;

and $[t/x]F$ is called a *substitution instance* or *substitution* or *substituted* after $x$ is replaced by $t$.

---

Here, both substituting and substituted are used to be nouns.

Comment: I predict you will find no dictionary agreeing with your claim for "substituent".  Substituent is jargon specific to chemistry.